# how to write bytes data in file swift

Tags: ios, swift

data coming from server is in ex.2035bytes I want to write this data in to file I am writing but data is not showing

```
Alamofire.request(url , method: .post, parameters: Parameters as? [String: Any] , encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]).responseData{ (response) in
            print(response)
            print(response.result.value!)
            print(response.result.description)

            guard let jsonData = response.result.value ,response.result.isSuccess else {
                didFail(response.result.error!)
                return
            }
            guard let id = ApplicantModel.shared.applicationId else {
                return
            }
            let file = "application_\(id)" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

            let documentsPath1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
            //let logsPath = documentsPath1.appendingPathComponent("f")
             let fileURL = documentsPath1.appendingPathComponent("file")
             let data: Data = response.result.value!
           // print(logsPath)

            //writing
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: documentsPath1 as URL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

                //try data.write(to: fileURL!, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
               // try data.write(to: fileURL!, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
             try data.write(to: fileURL!) )

            }
            catch {/* error handling here */}

            let json = JSON(jsonData)
            didFinish(json)
    }
```

here I am creating file and writing data in to it but its not showing

Comment: Do you have an error in the catch block?? Did you try just to create the file in another folder?

Comment: What kind of data is this? You haven't added the file extension to the file name. After writing the file how do you open it ?

Comment: Replace `/* error handling here */` with `print(error)`. In the line `let fileURL = documentsPath1.appendingPathComponent("file")` you name the file to "file", perhaps you meant the content of the variable `file`? Could you please add to your question the expected path and name for the stored file.

Comment: response.result.value doesn't give Data. If you want Data you should use response.data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use this function to write data. Code is self explanatory, but I tried to make it more clear.**

```
func writeToFile(data: Data, fileName: String){
    // get path of directory
    guard let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last else {
        return
    }
    // create file url
    let fileurl =  directory.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).txt")
// if file exists then write data
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileurl.path) {
        if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileurl.path) {
            // seekToEndOfFile, writes data at the last of file(appends not override)
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.write(data)
            fileHandle.closeFile()
        }
        else {
            print("Can't open file to write.")
        }
    }
    else {
        // if file does not exist write data for the first time
        do{
            try data.write(to: fileurl, options: .atomic)
        }catch {
            print("Unable to write in new file.")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with creating the directory and naming the file you need to change it like this

```
        let file = "application_\(id)"
        let documentsPath1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
        let logsPath = documentsPath1.appendingPathComponent("file")
        do
        {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: logsPath!.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

            let fileURL = logsPath?.appendingPathComponent(file)
            try data.write(to: fileURL!)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you create a wrong folder. It due to you can't save that file in your folder. You can look at my example. Which I create 1 folder to contain files.

Step1: Get document path

`let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)`

Step2: create a destination URL. Where you would like to store

`let url = paths[0].appendingPathComponent(self.fileImagejpeg)`

Step 3: Write data in files

`try? data.write(to: url)`

You can use try catch to get log when write failure